# When using multiple imputation, is it more informative to report descriptive statistics for the imputed dataset, the original dataset or both?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, missing-data, multiple-imputation, reporting

My understanding is that multiple imputation is a method for dealing with bias/lack of power that results from missing data. However, it is not a method for replacing individual values. As a result, I would assume that when reporting descriptive statistics for a dataset (e.g. means, frequencies and so on) you should use non-imputed data. This also provides the reader with information about the dataset that the imputation was based on. What is the purpose of reporting descriptive statistics based on pooled estimates? Is it useful and should it be reported? Are there any drawbacks to reporting descriptive statistics based on the original dataset, provided that you have detailed the amount and location of missing data in that dataset?

Comment: It is a method for replacing value, that's what it stands for "imputate" and depending on the field it is avoided.  It is to make sure your imputation did not change the nature of the sample. So it is about transparency about what you are doing. You want to see the spread, the shape of the data etc.. Presenting your data before and after data manipulation is thus good practice the requirements of which would also depend on the field you are in. .. pooled data would show you were the imputation had the biggest impact I guess.